# Interpolate Values in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list with about 200,000 tick values (date and value). The list does *not* have a tick value for every date. But this is what I need in my output. So I need something to add the missing tick values in the gaps.

I am using the Java Stream API to process the list.

```
class Tick {
    public LocalDate date;
    public BigDecimal value;

    public Tick(LocalDate date, BigDecimal value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class DateInterpolator {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final ArrayList<Tick> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Tick(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1), BigDecimal.valueOf(7)));
        list.add(new Tick(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 3), BigDecimal.valueOf(8)));

        final Stream<Tick> stream = list.stream();

        // TODO no value for 2017-01-02 given.
        // I want to use the value from the day before (7).
        // Add black magic here.
    }

}
```

Is it possible to add values to the stream or can I get a resulting stream containing no gaps? Can I do the look-ahead (to detect gaps) with streams at all?

Comment: From what I understand, you don't want to add elements to stream (because you can't, streams don't contain any data), but to your list, and yes, it is definitely possible, just add 1 day all the time and check if that date is in the list.

Comment: The value of the day before would be "7".

Ok, let me rephrase: Can I get a resulting stream containing no gaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether there are gaps by tracking the previous value. One way to do this is to access the list directly based on the entry's index. The following solution expects the input to be sorted by date.

```
final Stream<Tick> stream = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
  .mapToObj((i) -> {
    // 'sub' should contain one item. If there are gaps, 
    // sub will contain gap values as well, up to and including the current Tick.
    final ArrayList<Tick> sub = new ArrayList<>();

    Tick curr = list.get(i);

    if(i > 0) {
      Tick prev = list.get(i-1);

      // Fill the gaps if there are any
      for (LocalDate date = prev.date.plusDays(1); date.isBefore(curr.date); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
         sub.add(new Tick(date, prev.value));
      }
    }

    sub.add(curr); // add the current value

    return sub;
  })
  .flatMap(List::stream);
```

Or a stream based implementation:

```
private static Stream<Tick> fillGaps(Stream<Tick> ticks) {

    final Var prev = new Var(); // required to be final, so a wrapper is needed to modify the instance

    Stream<Tick> result = ticks
        .map(curr -> {
            final ArrayList<Tick> sub = new ArrayList<>();

            if(prev.instance != null) {
                for (LocalDate date = prev.instance.date.plusDays(1); date.isBefore(curr.date); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
                    sub.add(new Tick(date, prev.instance.value));
                }
            }

            sub.add(curr);
            prev.instance = curr;

            return sub;
        })
        .flatMap( l -> l.stream());

    return result;
}

// Helper class
class Var {
    public Tick instance; 
}

// Usage:
final Stream<Tick> ticks = fillGaps(stream);
```

`flatMap` flattens the intermediate result (created by `mapToObject`/`map`):

```
[
    Tick(2017-1-1, 7) // Last item is always an item in the original list
],
[
    Tick(2017-1-2, 7), // Interpolated value based on the previous value
    Tick(2017-1-3, 8) // Last item is always an item in the original list
]
```

Feel free to correct me in case anything is wrong.

Comment: Ok, but in "real life" I don't have a list to begin with. I have only an incoming stream and want to avoid creating a list containing all elements.

Comment: I've added a sample that uses streams.

Comment: Will stream based implementation always work for parallel stream?

Comment: The array based implementation may work, but the stream based implementation will not as it requires the previous value in order to work.